# Le maître/l'artisan/le maître(-)artisan/le maître-... serrurier/rôtisseur : nuances ou uniformité de l'usage moderne des composés du métier ?

Tags: sens, usage, professions, lexique, trait-d-union

Il y a plusieurs emplois et usages du mot [maître](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ma%C3%AEtre) en composition avec le *nom de celui/celle qui exerce un métier*. On nous explique au TLFi que du Moyen-âge jusqu'au 19e on entendait du maître « [c]elui qui, ayant accompli son apprentissage et réalisé le chef-d’œuvre, avait obtenu les lettres de maîtrise et était reçu dans un corps de métier (ce qui lui conférait le droit d'avoir des compagnons et des apprentis) », comme un *maître charpentier*. C'est un contexte où on a des « traditions de corporation et de compagnonnage » associées au titre ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ma%C3%AEtre/48734?q=ma%C3%AEtre#48646)). Mais il y a aussi plusieurs emplois où le maître est une personne qui « dirige des ouvriers, des employés, des subordonnés », soit le *patron*, ou le *chef d'équipe*, où l'on retrouve les *maître/maîtresse d'atelier, maître charpentier, maître menuisier* et éventuellement des emplois plus spécialisés comme le *maître d'équipage* dans le domaine nautique, par exemple (TLFi II. A. 2. a, b, c).

Par ailleurs on a aussi le *maître(-)artisan* ou l'[*artisan*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/artisan), celui qui exerce un *art mécanique* ou un *métier manuel* avec les qualifications professionnelles et le processus de certification qui y sont souvent associés. Le terme *artisan* peut être antéposé (la spécialisation ou plus rarement, nous dit-on, la fonction) ou postposé (quand il est secondaire à une autre activité, par exemple) au substantif du métier etc. En combinant le lexique on a des exemples comme *artisan serrurier*, *maître artisan ferronnier*, *artisan relieur* ou *maître en serrurerie d'art*, avec la préposition *en*.  Pour clore ce bref survol, on produit la remarque sous le *maître-artisan* :

> Rem. La langue commerciale actuelle abonde en composés où le 1er
>   élément maître semble seulement destiné à indiquer l'habileté de celui
>   qui exerce le métier en question. *Maître-tapissier, maître-verrier. 8 Français sur 10 pourraient recevoir leurs amis autour d'un feu de bois. R.L.D., maître-atrier répond à leurs questions* (*Femmes d'aujourd'hui*, 23 oct. 1968). *J.L., Maître-rôtisseur: Grillades au feu de bois* (*Le Monde*, 7 avril 1966 ds Gilb. Mots nouv. 1971).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi, à maître (II. B. 1.
>   b) ]

Et donc ces composés s'ajoutent à ceux qui précèdent de sorte qu'on se demande comment s'y retrouver.

---

1. En ce qui a trait à celui ou à celle qui exerce un métier, à l'exclusion de l'idée de direction :

   - en quoi les composés *artisan/maître/maître(-)artisan* + [ nom de celui qui exerce ] ou [ en (nom du métier) ]  (artisan serrurier / maître serrurier / maître(-)artisan serrurier / *idem*... en serrurerie etc.) ont-ils une signification ou des connotations différentes le cas échéant ?

     - est-ce différent selon les catégories de métiers ou est-ce que ce sont
       toutes des variations du maître(-)artisan où un des termes tomberait avec tel ou tel usage ?
     - l'artisan constitue-t-il un sous-ensemble du maître, son extension
       ou son prolongement moderne ou a-t-on une réponse à une question plus intelligente sur le sujet ?
2. Avec le *maître* + [ nom de celui qui exerce ], comment distingue-t-on
   généralement dans une phrase qu'il s'agisse du *dirigeant/chef* ou du
   *professionnel* ?
3. Les emplois de *maître* destinés à indiquer l'*habileté* de celui qui
   exerce, et dont on discute en remarque, contiennent-ils toujours le
   *trait d'union* ; au final est-ce en ce sens (la grande habileté) que l'on comprendrait de prime abord aujourd'hui tous les composés avec *maître* qui précèdent (1&2) ?

Comment: Je sais que l'anglais ne nous intéresse pas dans cette question, mais j'ai entendu à la radio ce matin _master salesman_, ce qui montre que cette idée de _maître qqch_ existe aussi en anglais avec le sens d'_habileté supérieure_ (et peut même être utilisé ironiquement).

Answer (score 2):

A mon avis *la grande habileté* est le dénominateur commun. Je pense pas que l'on fasse de fortes distinctions suivant le sens de *dirigeant* ou non de nos jours, sauf peut-être cas spécialisés dans certains métiers (dont je ne suis pas au courant). En général, on comprend *maître* avant un nom comme étant un *grade* supérieur au mot non qualifié: le *maître artisan* est un meilleur artisan que le simple *artisan*, le *maître ouvrier* est un meilleur *ouvrier*, et ainsi de suite. Je pense que l'emploi moderne du mot *maître* devant un nom de métier s'utilise plutôt pour des métiers manuels. Je n'ai jamais entendu *maître docteur* ou bien *maître mathématicien*. Je pense que cette appellation est vieille et se rencontre plutôt dans des contextes très traditionnels.