# La substance de l'activité de celui qui forge, la familiarité avec les noms de ses spécialités, et le haut degré du « traditionnel » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, professions, lexique

On a le métier du [*forgeron*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forgeron), celui ou celle qui, de manière artisanale, « travaille à la forge et façonne (le fer) à l'aide du feu et du marteau » ou, en contexte industriel, généralement l'ouvrier qui « travaille à la fabrication des métaux » (TLFi). Parfois on donne des exemples de spécialités du métier, comme *[taillandier](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8363185), [coutelier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coutelier), [serrurier](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19498845), [ferronnier (d'art)](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19021903), [ferron](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ferron), [maréchal-ferrant](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17485828), [dinandier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dinandier)*. Peut-être différemment, on a aussi vu l'[*outilleur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/outilleur). Essentiellement, je n'en connais aucun et de manière usuelle le [serrurier](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17024144) est pour moi celui qui s'occupe de serrures, et je ne savais même pas qu'il pouvait *forger des fers de petite section* ni ce que ça pourrait vouloir dire. Chez Larousse, on présente le [*forgeron*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/forgeron/34612?q=forgeron#34571) comme l'« artisan forgeant à la main diverses pièces de petites et moyennes dimensions » mais aussi l'ouvrier qui travaille les métaux par [forgeage](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/forgeage/34608), essentiellement avec l'aide de moulages/matrices. On ne sait pas exactement si aujourd'hui le [*forgeage*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forgeage) n'est pas exclusivement de sens [techno-industriel](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17028746). On sait que la [forgerie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forgerie) n'est pas reliée au métier de *forgeron*. Par ailleurs on y explique le [*ferronnier*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ferronnier/33381/locution?q=ferronnier#171822) ([fiche onisep](http://www.onisep.fr/Ressources/Univers-Metier/Metiers/ferronnier-ferronniere-d-art)) comme étant un « ferronnier d'art, serrurier ou [métallier](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17575858) hautement qualifié, capable de concevoir et d'exécuter des pièces (pentures, grilles, rampes et balcons métalliques, etc.) présentant une recherche artistique » (Larousse). On a le *maître artisan [ferronnier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ferronnier)*, où joliment la partie d'art du ferronnier semble substantiver l'artisan, et le *maître [forgeron](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forgeron)* (alors que le *maître des forges* est le « propriétaire d'importantes aciéries dont il assure la direction et l'administration »(TLFi).) ; on a déjà abordé l'emploi du terme [*maître*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25089) en contexte du métier ailleurs. Quant au substantif [*forge*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forge), il peut servir autant pour l'atelier où l'on [forge](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forge) que par métonymie pour le fourneau utilisé. Enfin parfois on peut retrouver certains compositions comme *forgeron-coutelier*.

---

1. Y a-t-il un mot employé pour désigner le domaine dans lequel le *forgeron* exerce son métier, tel qu'on a *ferronnerie* pour ferronnier, *serrurerie* pour serrurier etc. ? *Ferronnerie* sert-il de substantif ici aussi, ou s'agit-il plutôt du *forgeage*, ou plutôt d'un autre emploi par métonymie du mot *forge* ? Sait-on brièvement pourquoi *forgerie* n'est-il jamais devenu un dérivé en [*-erie*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-erie) comme les autres pour l'activité artistique ou industrielle dont on parle ?
2. On dit qu'avec *ferronnerie* « la base du nom d'agent n'est plus
   sentie en français contemporain » (TLFi). Est-ce toujours le cas ?
   A-t-on une familiarité, en France par exemple, avec une des spécialités du métier de
   forgeron ou avec un des termes mentionnés, dans son sens artisanal,
   comme on l'aurait par exemple avec la *boulangerie* ou la
   *pâtisserie* : avec laquelle, à quel degré ?
3. En regardant le [profil](http://mathieucollette.ca/parcours-artistique/) d'un maître-artisan dans le domaine (au
   Québec), qui a une formation en *ferronnerie d'art*, des cours en
   *ferronnerie* et de *serrurerie*, qui mentionne des *traditions classiques de taillanderie et de forge d'arme*, qu'on présente comme
   *artisan du métal* dans une [émission](http://zonevideo.telequebec.tv/media/31333/375e-forgeron/les-francs-tireurs), *maître forgeron* dans quelques articles ([1](http://ici.radio-canada.ca/emissions/le_15_18/2016-2017/chronique.asp?idChronique=415893), [2](http://www.ledevoir.com/politique/montreal/492802/les-forges-de-montreal-sauvees)), et où lui-même parle dans une
   [entrevue](http://www.lapresse.ca/videos/201611/25/46-1-lappel-de-la-forge.php/c493adf21ec2481dbf23f9ff0f83e899) de *forgeron*, de *professionnels-artisans* et de
   *forge traditionnelle*, se donnant comme mission de produire *tous les outils servant au travail du bois, de la pierre, et en
   agriculture* ; [etc.](https://www.lesforgesdemontreal.org/fr/press/). : a-t-on mieux ou plus précis que
   l'adjectif « traditionnel » pour préciser la vocation ou le sens
   qu'on donne à sa spécialité ici ; connaît-on un élément formant
   comme [*paléo-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pal%C3%A9o-) mais en moins vieux et applicable à l'univers
   des métiers et qui pourrait être utile ?

Comment: Question pointue qui requiert l'opinion d'un forgeron :-) Pour _paléo-_, l'adjectif _ancien_ peut parfois jouer ce rôle.

Comment: Sans répondre complètement, il me semble ce qui dérive de "forge" fait état d'un travail nécessitant de former des outils pour l'homme par la forge (au sens de fourneau) rejoignant ainsi la définition du Larousse.
Concernant la première question, en reprenant le terme anglais "blacksmithing" qui retranscrit le travail du forgeron, on obtient forge comme traduction sur linguee.
http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/blacksmithing.html

Comment: @Blue_Elephant Merci ! Je suis plutôt familier avec le [lexique](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/240622) de la forge en langue anglaise. Je ne suis pas certain de saisir la nuance que vous faites et en quoi linguee nous serait d'aucun secours, mais une réponse partielle est possible, ce qui permettrait d'expliquer plus avant.

Comment: @redahabsinpeach Quand bien même linguee est un recueil de traductions un peu arbitraire, il permet toutefois de comprendre comment un terme est percu par de nombreuses personnes sensées maîtriser les caractéristiques des deux langues. Ainsi (je suis brièvement hors-sujet) les éléments de traduction sur linguee dont la source provient du parlement européen par exemple attestent à mon avis une certaine authenticité.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant Euh, bien je ne comprends pas pourquoi nous discutons de la valeur de linguee, je n'ai pas d'opinion là-dessus. Je comprends ce que vous dites mais pas en quoi ce serait applicable à la question. Je ne m'intéresse aucunement au gens sensés maîtriser les caractéristiques de deux langues, je m'intéresse à la langue française et à ses locuteurs. Mais vous êtes libre de motiver l'emploi du mot _forge_ de la manière que vous l'entendez. N'hésitez pas à répondre directement en réponse, ce qui pourrait attirer l'attention et permettre à d'autres personnes de commenter etc. Merci !

Comment: Link rot. 3.@profil/ waybackmachine : https://web.archive.org/web/20180815174328/http://mathieucollette.ca/parcours-artistique/ Ah, les Forges de Montréal ont [20 ans](https://lesforgesdemontreal.org/pages/notre-histoire) et sont accréditées par l'[UNESCO](https://ich.unesco.org/fr-etat/canada-CA?info=ong-accreditees#ngo-01272). Félicitations !

Answer (score 2):

Le domaine dans lequel un forgeron exerce son métier est la *forge*.
Comme par exemple une [formation en fonderie et forge](http://www.a3f-forge-fonderie.fr/nos-domaines-de-formations/).

Ce n'est pas le seul  domaine qui ne fini pas en *ie*. Il existe aussi le domaine de l'informatique par exemple.

Ce que la menuiserie est au menuisier, la forge est au forgeron.